# WinForms Application: Russian Spell Checker

Tags: winforms

I'm trying to do a spell check of the Russian language in WinFormApp when entering a text field, but nothing comes out, tell me how to get out of the situation, what are your ideas? What is missing, maybe a dictionary, how to connect it and where is it stored?

```
public void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost elementHost1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost();
        System.Windows.Controls.TextBox richTextBox1 = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox();
        richTextBox1.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
        richTextBox1.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("ru-RU");
        elementHost1.Child = richTextBox1;
   }
```

Comment: You could use devExpress' SpellCheck control

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.spellcheck?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0 says only english spanish french and german

Comment: [SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.customdictionaries)

Comment: Hello Jordy Deweer there is a good example devExpress is code?

Comment: BTW, if you add a custom LEX dictionary, encode it using `Encoding.Unicode`.